# Re-route HVAC around basement window?

Tags: hvac

Working on my basement and this part of the HVAC covers the corner of that window. Can it be re-routed or reconfigured to fit around the window better? It connects to the kitchen upstairs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you may also be able to shorten the plenum so that it is not so close to the window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get some flexible HVAC duct and install it up there. It's only for one register so it shouldn't affect the cooling or heating.

Comment: I think I like this idea best.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a [register end boot](https://amzn.to/39G9zNI). But your tap into the rectangular duct may need to be closer to the end to get the rise to miss the TJI.

Comment: Oddly enough the previous home owner left one of those. I’ll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your floor joists are manufactured I-joists, like this:

https://www.fp-supply.com/st-louis-trusjoist-tji-i-joists.html

If that's the case, they usually allow significant cutouts in the web (the thinner wood that connects the upper and lower flanges).  You might be able come out the side of the rectangular duct up and through the joist, then over to the register with a shallow duct or use the register boot like NoSparksPlease suggested.

You would need the information sheet for your joists to see what cutouts are allowed - how big and where along the web.

Comment: actually there is what looks like a packet attached to one of them that might have that info in it. I'll take a look. But how the bulkhead is being built, running it alongside the plenum really isn't an issue, just trying to avoid blocking that window.